# brew doctor Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin

Tags: homebrew

When I run `brew doctor`, I get the following error:

```
Error: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
```

This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by `Homebrew`. The following tools exist at both paths.

How to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to fix it

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

And change all lines like this

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

And than check PATH values on new terminal tab

```
env|grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Restart your terminal and run

```
brew doctor
```

Everythings OK.